# htaccess redirect to non-www from www

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, cakephp, cpanel

I saw duplicates on this title but to be frank i'm new to PHP and not sure how htaccess works. I had this script purchased from someone and i am not getting help from that developer which is why i'm the only one to solve this issue.

**Issue**
My old script was made by me which used to be redirected to *http://socialdealers.in/Deals/* and the new script is CakePHP based script which shows everything on the index but i still see the old redirection even after removing those files from the hosting.

**Website**
http://socialdealers.in

- Sometimes i see the updated script but sometimes it gets redirected
  to /Deals/
- Tried to clear browser cache and cookies
- Tried to open from my mobile with a different IP and it works with the new script.

I'm sorry if you guys did not understand what i am trying to say but any help would be appreciated. Some developer told me to ask a question here on stackoverflow and said that its .htaccess problem.

**Location 1 .htaccess**
public_html/socialdealers.in/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^445$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

**Location 2 .htaccess**
public_html/socialdealers.in/app/.htaccess

```
# Use PHP5 as default

#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Location 3 .htaccess**
public_html/socialdealers.in/app/webroot/.htaccess

```
# Use PHP5 as default

#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

EDIT:
Issue Resolved Outside Stackoverflow.

Edited the 3rd htaccess file and changed it to

```
# Use PHP5 as default

#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: is your old and new script hosted on same server? if hosted on a new server, domain A records will take time to work everywhere(atleast 72 hours sometimes to work) - and also share the htaccess code

Comment: Its already more than 72 hours. The old script still shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved Outside Stackoverflow.

Edited the 3rd htaccess file and changed it to

```
# Use PHP5 as default

#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the links you post direct me to `/Deals/`, which is a login/ signup page.  Is this not your goal?

(1) If you think the problem is with the `.htaccess` file, can you show the content of your `.htaccess` to help us all (including you) resolve your issue.  The `.htaccess` file is located on your web server, likely in the root folder of your website.

An example of a simple redirect in `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
Redirect 301 /OLDFILE.html /NEWFILE.html
```

Another example of redirection using regex on all pages, to force non-www, could look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^YOURDOMAIN.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.YOURDOMAIN.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://YOURDOMAIN.net/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

(2) If you think the problem is with your PhP code, then can you also post more information on how you set up your redirect or simply show some of the code.

Comment: I have added 3 .htaccess in different folders. I'll share the paths and the codes to the htaccess in the main question.